What are the actual holdings in VFIIX mutual fund?
I'm looking at investing part of my portfolio in VFIIX Vanguard GNMA Fund Investor Shares, and I'm trying to get more detail about what the holdings are. Vanguard's holding details page shows a bunch of line items for Government National Mortgage Assn. and some for Federal National Mortgage Assn. and United States Treasury Inflation Indexed Bonds and others. What is this actually investing in?
I reviewed Vanguard's GNMA page, and saw

The Government National Mortgage Association (GNMA or Ginnie Mae) issues agency bonds backed by the full faith and credit of the U.S. government. GNMA guarantees principal and interest on mortgage-backed securities (MBS) backed by loans insured by the Federal Housing Administration and the Department of Veterans Affairs.

But I'm still not clear on what is actually funded by these bonds. Does "loans insured by FHA and VA" mean that the bonds are funding the agencies of FHA and VA? Or are they funding other government agencies? If so, which ones? Specifically I'd like to avoid this if it funds the Department of Defense.

Without looking at the actual prospectus, I strongly suspect that these ETFs hold "mortgage bonds" which are essentially thousands of mortgages wrapped into a product that pays out to investors as people pay their mortgages. There are other types of "securitized products" for other types of loans, but identifying them as GNMA (or "Ginny Mae") suggests that they are residential mortgages.

Does "loans insured by FHA and VA" mean that the bonds are funding the agencies of FHA and VA?

No - it means that the mortgages within these bonds are guaranteed by the government, meaning if someone doesn't pay their mortgage, those government agencies ensure that the bank (or bond in this case) is repaid.
The agencies are not paid when someone pays their mortgage, the bank/bond that holds the mortgage gets the payment.

Specifically I'd like to avoid this if it funds the Department of Defense.

It's a different story for the Treasury bonds and Inflation-linked bonds that the fund holds. The money that is obtained from issuing these bonds does go to the government, which pays back the bond holder over time in principal and interest. So in a sense you're loaning money to the government, which at the end of the day is one big pool - no single department gets paid directly.
More specifically, if you buy units of VFIIX it's possible that they use that money to buy treasury bonds, which gives money to the government, of which a portion would be spent by the DoD.
You can decide for yourself if that's a disqualifying characteristic.
